# Correct way of uploading appDsyms.zip on Firebase Crashlytics using upload-symbols

Tags: ios, firebase, crashlytics

I've been trying to upload dSYMs on Crashlytics which works but this script searches for each and every DSYMs in all my directories on iMac instead of just the one which I want to upload. I'm using following command

```
/path/to/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp /path/
to/GoogleService-Info.plist -p <platform> /path/to/dSYMs
```

Is it normal and intended behaviour? If not, then how do I just upload the appDsyms.zip which I want to upload?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to specify specific appDsyms.zip path instead and should work.

> /path/to/Fabric/upload-symbols -gsp /path/ to/GoogleService-Info.plist
>   -p  /path/to/appDsyms.zip